# nested select (SQL Server)

Tags: sql

I'm not sure exactly how to get this.

What I have is something like this.

```
TableA:  VisitID, PersonID1, PersonID2
TableB:  PersonID, FirstName, LastName
```

I'd like to return Visit ID, name of PersonID1, name of personID2.

Usually I would just do a simple join, but I can't seem to get that to work

It should go something like

```
SELECT A.VisitID, B.FirstName+B.LastName, B.FirstName+B.LastName (this is dup, wont work)
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B ON TableA.PersonID1=TableB.PersonID OR TableA.PersonID2=TableB.PersonID
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to join `tableb` twice, once for each id:

```
select VisitID, b1.FirstName, b1.LastName, b2.FirstName, b2.LastName
from TableA
        inner join TableB b1 on TableA.PersonID1=b1.PersonID
        inner join TableB b2 on TableA.PersonID2=b2.PersonID
```

Comment: This works great (as do the other answers), Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
select A.VisitID, B1.FirstName+B1.LastName, B2.FirstName+B2.LastName
from TableA A
    join TableB B1 on A.PersonID1 = B1.PersonId
    join TableB B2 on A.PersonID2 = B2.PersonId
```

essentially, you join with `TableB` twice, once per foreign key in `TableA`

Answer (score 2):

I think simple inner join two times should do the trick.

```
select A.VisitID, (BB.FirstName + ' ' + BB.LastName) as Person1, 
(BC.FirstName + ' ' + BC.LastName) as Person2
from TableA A
inner join TableB BB on A.PersonID1 = BB.PersonId
inner join TableB BC on A.PersonID2 = BC.PersonId
```

Answer (score 1):

If PersonID1/PersonID2 are nullable, the join has to be left join

```
Select
      A.VisitID
    , B1.FirstName + ' ' + B1.LastName
    , B2.FirstName + ' ' + B2.LastName
From
    TableA A
Left Join
    TableB B1
On
    A.PersonID1 = B1.PersonID
Left Join
    TableB B2
On
    A.PersonID1 = B2.PersonID
```

Comment: Yes but if `personid1/2` are nullable, then maybe this approach isn't the best anyway. An ID linking to a list of person ID's would be better.